# Avoid selection onClick

Tags: jqgrid

I would like to prevent onClick selection on an element of jqGrid.

How is it possible??

Here is an example for you

Go to this link http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/UnobtrusiveLinksNew.htm

In this page if I click on **Michael Schumacher** or **Lukas Podolski** related row become selected with yellow color. On the other hand if I click on **Formula 1**  or **Football** related rows are not selecting. I would like to get this behaviour upon an element in jqGrid.

**UPDATE:**
Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    {

$(function()
    { 
      $("#list").jqGrid
      ({
            url:'example.php',
            datatype: 'xml',
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames:['RABR member in Circle','Date Sent','Status','Action'],
            colModel :
            [ 

              {name:'tax', index:'tax', width:85, align:'left',sortable:false,formatter:format_row},
              {name:'invdate', index:'invdate', width:60, align:'center',sortable:false,formatter:format_date}, 
              {name:'amount', index:'amount', width:35, align:'center', sortable:false,formatter:format_status},
              {name:'amount', index:'amount', width:55, align:'left',title:false, sortable:false,formatter:format_rate_me,beforeSelectRow: function(rowid, e) { return false; },
}, 
            ],
            pager: '#pager',
            rowNum:10,
            rowList:[10,20,30],
            viewrecords: true,
            multiselect: true,
            altclass:'myAltRowClass',
            altRows:true,
            width:624,
            height:'auto' }).navGrid('#pager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false}); 
        }) ;    


        function format_row(cellValue, options, rowObject) 
            {
                var split_result = cellValue.split("+");
                var show_result= "<img src='images1/" + split_result[0] + "'/><b id='pro_name'>"+ split_result[1] + "</b></br><b id='e_add'>" + split_result[2]+"</b>";
                return show_result;
            }


        function format_date(cellValue, options, rowObject) 
            {
                var date = "<div class='date'>" + cellValue + "</div>";
                return date;
            }


        function format_status(cellValue, options, rowObject) 
            {
                var status_image = "<img src='images/" + cellValue + ".jpg' />";
                return status_image;
            }   


        function format_rate_me(cellValue, options, rowObject) 
            {   
                var optoins = "<div class='rate_me_text'>" + cellValue + "<div class='star_div'></div><div class='down_arrow'></div>   <div class='options'><ul><li class='add_me'><a href='#'>Add as a friend</a></li><li class='view_circle'><a href='#'>View Circle Members(23)</a></li><li class='send_msg'><a href='#'>Send messages</a></li><li class='add_to_watch'><a href='#'>Add to watch list</a></li><li class='gifting'><a href='#'>Give a gift</a></li><li class='remove'><a href='#'>Remove from Circle</a></li><li class='block'><a href='#'>Block</a></li><li class='report'><a href='#'>Report abuse</a></li></ul></div></div>";              
                return optoins;
            }

    });
```

I would like to get avoid selection on click upon .down_arrow class.

thanks for reply

**UPDATE**

"@Oleg"

Finally I done it .

here is the code

```
altclass:'myAltRowClass',
        altRows:true,
        beforeSelectRow: 
        function(rowid, e) 
        { 
            var iCol = $.jgrid.getCellIndex(e.target);

            if (iCol >=4) 
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        },
        width:624,
```

Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent selection of the row you can use [beforeSelectRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents#list_of_events) event handler. If the event handler returns false the row selection will be prevented. You can examine `e.target` which will be the `<td>` element where the user clicked or its child element (like `<a>` element inside of `<td>`).

Comment: How can I use beforeSelectRow ??
Where can I use beforeSelectRow??
Is it use within colModel or out side of colModel ??

I used customformatter in my coloumn.

I got following code in Events page of wiki

`var lastSel;
jQuery("#gridid").jqGrid({
...
   onSelectRow: function(id){ 
      if(id && id!==lastSel){ 
         jQuery('#gridid').restoreRow(lastSel); 
         lastSel=id; 
      } 
      jQuery('#gridid').editRow(id, true); 
   },
...
});`

But it is not clear to me. Could you please send some examples about that??

Comment: @Foysal: You can use `beforeSelectRow` on the same level and in the same way as you use `onSelectRow`. For another demo look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CellClick1.htm) and click on an icon inside of grid. If you still have some question you can include some *your* code in your question (not in the comment) and I could insert `beforeSelectRow` handle in your code.

Comment: @Foysal: I am here. What's the problem? Do you tried the `beforeSelectRow` event? By the way if you want to write a message to my you should use "@Oleg" syntax (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020))

Comment: @Foysal: Next time if you make any modification in your question you should short write about it. I answer on many questions and not reread every question on a new comment. Why you don't use `beforeSelectRow` like I described before? Moreover I can only read your code and can't test it till you post any test XML data which you use. Moreover the `div.down_arrow` is just an empty div having width 0 and height 0. How the user can click on it?

Comment: "@Oleg" I posted my code as per your requirement. I did not use beforeSelectRow. I am waiting for your comment and revised code along with beforeSelectRow. Thanks for reply.